# Show that a function is finite but unbounded in a algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have the following problem:

> Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the algebra of finite disjoint unions of right-semiclosed intervals of $\mathbb{R}$, and define the set function $\mu$ on $\mathcal{F}$ as follows:
>   \begin{align*}
> \mu(-\infty,a] &= a, &&a\in\mathbb{R}\\
> \mu(a,b] &= b-a, &&a,b\in\mathbb{R}, a<b\\
> \mu(b,\infty) &= -b, &&b\in\mathbb{R}\\
> \mu(\mathbb{R}) &= 0
> \end{align*}
>   (a) Show that $\mu$ is finitely additive but not countably additive on $\mathcal{F}$.
>
> (b) Show that $\mu$ is finite but unbounded on $\mathcal{F}$.

The letter (a) is quite straightforward. I just need to show that
$$\mu\left(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{n} A_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n\mu(A_i)$$
And that it's not valid for $n\to\infty$

For the letter (b), that $\mu$ is finite it's ok, but I don't know how to show it's unbounded. Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show that $\mu$ is unbounded, we need to show that for any $M > 0$, there exists some interval $(a,b]$ such that $\mu(a,b] > M$.  So, fix $M > 0$ and take
$$ a < -\frac{M}{2}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
b > \frac{M}{2}. $$
Then we have
$$ \mu(a,b]
= b-a
> \frac{M}{2} + \frac{M}{2}
= M, $$
which gets the job done.